# Unable to sort singly linked list into 3 different singly linked list

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have a splitter=5 and I want to sort the data of singly linked list by splitter. Like

> "list_1" -> Holds the data which are less than 5
>
> "list_2" -> Holds thedata which are equal to 5
>
> "list_3" -> Holds the data which are greater than 5

But on calling the sort function it exits without any error.

```
nodal *sort(nodal *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data<splitter)
        {
            start_1=insert_end(start_1,ptr->data);
        }
        else if(ptr->data==splitter)
        {
            start_2=insert_end(start_2,ptr->data);
        }
        else
        {
            start_3=insert_end(start_3,ptr->data);
        }
    }
    return start;
}
nodal *insert_end(nodal *start,int num)
{
    nodal *new_node,*ptr;
    new_node = (nodal *)malloc(sizeof(nodal));
    new_node->data=num;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
       new_node->next=NULL;
        start=new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->next=NULL;
        ptr = start;
        while (ptr!= NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=new_node;
    }
    
    return start;
}
```

My function calling

```
int main()
{
    int options;
    do
    {
        printf("\n 1.Create node");
        
        printf("\n 6.Display");
        
        printf("\n 3.Display Sorted");
        printf("\n 4.Sort the given list");
        printf("\n Enter you choice \n");
        scanf("%d",&options);
        
        switch (options)
        {
            case 1:
                start = create(start);
                break;
                
            case 2:
                display(start);
                break;
                
            case 3:
                start = display_sorted(start_1,start_2,start_3);
                break;
            case 4:
                start = sort(start);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }while(options!=13);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of your inputs? Are you also using global variables? Importantly, also provide the context in which you call the sort function, as you may be passing a null pointer to start off with.

Comment: @AJD Inputs are int value. Yes I am using global variable splitter=5. I am calling sort function like start=sort(start). And start is globally declared as nodal *start = NULL ;
nodal *start_2 = NULL ;
nodal *start_1 = NULL ;
nodal *start_3 = NULL ;

Comment: `printf("\n 6.Display");` -> `printf("\n 2.Display");`

Comment: @shobhit: Adding those details to your question will help future answers. Cheers.

Comment: That's just typo error @4386427 I am calling it by 2 itself.

Comment: will keep hat in mind @AJD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert_end` function is wrong.

In the code below you iterate until `ptr` becomes NULL and then you dereference `ptr`. That will fail (i.e. undefined behavior).

```
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr!= NULL)   // Will continue until ptr is NULL
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next=new_node;  // Ups - dereference of NULL pointer
```

Perhaps try:

```
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
```

Another observation is that you never use the value return by `insert_end`. That is probably a mistake.

Maybe you want to do:

```
start_1 = insert_end(start_1, ptr->data);
```

Further there is a problem in `sort` - you never change `ptr`

```
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    if(ptr->data<splitter)
    {
        start_1=insert_end(start_1,ptr->data);
    }
    else if(ptr->data==splitter)
    {
        start_2=insert_end(start_2,ptr->data);
    }
    else
    {
        start_3=insert_end(start_3,ptr->data);
    }

    // This line is missing
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: @SHOBHITSRIVASTAVA17BIT0292 Your description is unclear. What do you mean by `Exiting without any error`? What error did you expect?

Comment: It's not showing any output. I am expecting menu after it as I am using a menu driven program so after executing sort function it should display the menu but it just exits. Check he update of question

Comment: I also have inserted the menu in the question please check it.

Comment: @SHOBHITSRIVASTAVA17BIT0292 See updated answer. And you should also post the `display_sorted` function